# Award BIOS CMOS Setup Utility in my Vista

Tags: virtualization, intel

I want to check if my computer supports Virtualization Technology (VT-x). If supports, will try to turn on VT-x and install HAXM. When my computer start up, I got

Phoenix - Award BIOS CMOS Setup Utility, followed by
Advanced Chipset Features
System Info
Standard CMOS Features
Advanced BIOS Features
Boot Device Configuration
Integrated Peripherals

Can you tell me where I should go to turn on VT-x and install HAXM?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Post the specifications of your processor. It may or may not be compatible with VT-x.

Answer (score 1):

Try to google your motherboard model and find out the specs.
Or you can access your computer bios enter inside bios by pressing the delete button or the F2 button depending on your motherboard vendor.

Entering inside bios is dangerous try not to make any changes that you don't understand.

About the VT-x is usually enabled by default in all modern motherboards.

Comment: In the Advanced BIOS Features for my computer, the items look not useful:   
CPU Feature   
Limit CPUID Value   
Execute Disable Bit   
Core Multi-Processing

Comment: As hoki says in the comment above post your motherboard model and we will find if your motherboard supports , if you don't know your motherboard  model check this link http://www.nextofwindows.com/4-ways-to-find-out-whats-the-motherboard-model-inside-your-windows-7-machine/

Comment: Is these information usefull:     

wmic bios get name,serialnumber,version     
Name     SerialNumber      Version     
Phoenix - AwardBIOS v6.00PG   FQS773J     DELL - 42302e31     
     
wmic csproduct get name,identifyingnumber,uuid     
IdentifyingNumber    Name     UUID     
FQS773J                  Inspiron 530   4C4C4544-0051-5310-8037-C6C04F37334A     

wmic cpu get nme,CurrentClockSpeed,MaxClockSpeed     
CurrentClockSpeed MaxClockSpeed Name     
2000   2000   Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E4400 @ 2.00GHz

Comment: from your service tag i see in dell site that is an Inspiron 530 (Mid 2007) check this thread it supports also check for bios update in dell site.http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19515496